# override prepareForSegue doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

SecondViewController's Code

```
@IBAction func ContinueFunc(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if (NomeAziendaText.text != "" && NumeroBlocchiText.text != "" &&           NumeroMacroText.text != ""){
    nome = NomeAziendaText.text!
    na = Int(NumeroMacroText.text!)!
    nb = Int(NumeroBlocchiText.text!)!
    Azienda.inizia(name: nome, numbermacro: na, numberblocchi: nb)

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "next", sender: nil)
    }
    else {NomeAziendaText.text = ""
        NumeroBlocchiText.text = ""
        NumeroMacroText.text   = ""
        LabelAvvisi.text = " Inserisci tutti i valori"
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation*/

 func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("pippa")

    if (segue.identifier == "next"){
        if let vc_destinazione = segue.destination as?{


            vc_destinazione.stringaDiPassaggio = nome
        }

    }

    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}`
```

ThirdViewController's Code

```
 import UIKit
 class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
var stringaDiPassaggio: String = String()
var numero: Int = 0
@IBOutlet var Bottone: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  print(stringaDiPassaggio)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
    @IBAction func FunzioneBottone(_ sender: AnyObject) {

}

}`
```

Why no data pass from SecondViewController to ThirdViewController? 
If i override the method PrepareFor segue it show an error which say i doesn't override any method of super class

Help me please

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you have connected the view controllers and correct this

```
          performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)
```

then correct this

```
 if (segue.identifier == "next"){
    if let vc_destinazione = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController {


        vc_destinazione.stringaDiPassaggio = nome
    }

}
```

Comment: I've to inizialize vc_destinazione,what i've to do?

Comment: please answer this Q     did you connect your view controllers?

Comment: ThirdViewController is your next viewController

Comment: Yes to both Question

Comment: and remove this      if (segue.identifier == "next")

Answer (score 1):

The signature should be

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
}
```

You have

```
func prepare(for segue: ...
```

Comment: If I write  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {} xcode give me an error on on override word

Comment: What error is it giving? Are you actually subclassing UIViewController?

Comment: "Method does not ovveride any method from its superclass"

Comment: What version of Swift are you on? What is the superclass? This seems a pretty big clue that your method is not in the class you expect it to be, which would explain why it's not being called.

Comment: Version 8.0 i think the super class i UIViewcontroller